# How are the templates in the js_example module retrieved?

Tags: 8, theming

I installed [js_example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/js_example?h=8.x-1.x), one of the sample modules in the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.

In this module I found the following configuration:

```
css
 - jsweights.js
js
 - black.js
 - blue.js
 - brown.js
 - green.js
 - js_example_accordion.js
 - purple.js
 - red.js
src
 Controller
  - JsExampleController
templates
 - accordion.html.twig
 - description.html.twig
js_example.info.yml
js_example.libraries.yml
js_example.links.menu.yml
js_example.module
js_example.routing.yml
```

I do not understand how the template `description.html.twig` and `accordion.html.twig` are retrieved.

I miss this piece to understand the example completely.

In which file do I find the configuration I am looking for?

Comment: Drupal manages those files. You declare the templates in the yml file and then Drupal uses them when needed.

Comment: @sanzante – Which `*.yml` files are you thinking of which declare templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside [`js_example.module`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/js_example/js_example.module?h=8.x-1.x) there's a function which declares how a render array using a certain `'#theme'` is to be rendered as HTML and which variables might be available. This function is [`hook_theme`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x). It also can define a template that Drupal will look for inside the module's `template` folder.

```
function js_example_theme() {

  return [
    'js_example_accordion' => [
      'template' => 'accordion',
      'variables' => [
        'title' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Next there is the [`src/Controller/JsExampleController.php`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/js_example/src/Controller/JsExampleController.php?h=8.x-1.x) which has a function to output stuff and is told to use the `'js_example_accordion'`-`'#theme'` for that.

```
  public function getJsAccordionImplementation() {

    $title = $this->t('Click sections to expand or collapse:');

    $build['myelement'] = [
      '#theme' => 'js_example_accordion',
      '#title' => $title,
    ];

    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'js_example/js_example.accordion';

    return $build;
  }
```

That's the basics.

---

The `description.html.twig` is used a little bit differently but maybe just skip that for now as its some kind of advanced exception you'll understand later.

Comment: In the PHP controller I found this comment:

This class uses the DescriptionTemplateTrait to display text we put in the
 * templates/description.html.twig file.

Comment: Yeah, search the example module for `DescriptionTemplateTrait` and explore what you'll find there :)

Comment: I analyzed the content of the trait DescriptionTemplateTrait
Now it's clear :)

Comment: Cool, then please consider to upvote and accept this answer.